# google script Prevent duplicate data Submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I'm a beginner of learning google script.
I need to submit data from one sheet to another using google script. When I click `submitData`, it should check whether it is previously entered data or not. If previously entered data, code must stop. If it is new entry, data mast sent to "output" sheet. Can anybody help me to figure out my error?

EDIT:  I prepared a bio data format. I will share this google sheet among my school friends and asking to fill their details and click SUBMIT button. I want them to stop sending duplicate data. Their Identity Number is to be mention in "A3" cell. These data stored in "output" sheet. Identity number is stored in Column B. "A3" cell data match with Column B data in OUTPUT file and, if duplicate, msg prompt "duplicate".

Now When I run it , Data submitting to "output" sheet even DUPLICATE data entered in "A3" Cell.

```
 function submitData() {

 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("input"); //Data entry Sheet
 var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("output");
 var ttt       = formSS.getRange("A3").getValue();
 var values    = ss.getSheetByName("output").getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
      if (row[1] == ttt) {  //column B of the "output" sheet has project IDs (Unique Number)
          
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Duplicate data. you need to click  update');
      }
 else
{  
 var values = [[formSS.getRange("E2").getValue(),
                  formSS.getRange("A3").getValue()]],
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your script? What do you tried to test / debug it?

Comment: When I run it (I assigned the script to image and clicked) , Data submitting to "output" sheet even DUPLICATE data entered  in "A3" Cell.

Comment: Yes but you said that you don't want to send duplicate data and that is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @Cooper Actually my purpose is sending many cell data (in the input sheet) to another google sheet. I just made it simple here to learn :).  I will try to explain it in words now.  I prepared a bio data format. I will share this google sheet among my school friends and asking to fill their details and click SUBMIT button. I want them to stop sending duplicate data. Their Identity  Number is to be mention in "A3" cell. These data stored in "output" sheet. Identity number is stored in Column B. "A3" cell data match with Column B data in OUTPUT file and, if duplicate, msg prompt "duplicate"

Comment: What row does your friends data begin on?

Comment: @Rubén is eye opener to find out the mistake I did. Thanks all helps. **return row [1];** is the missing part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "error" is that there isn't anything that stop the script execution when `row[1] == ttt` is `true`. One possible fis is to add

```
return;
```

immediately after

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Duplicate data. you need to click  update');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function looks to see if an id matches with col B and if it does it updates and if it doesn't in adds a new row.

```
function submitOrUpdateData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const fsh = ss.getSheetByName("input");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("output");
  const did = fsh.getRange("A3").getValue();//data id
  const colB = dsh.getRange(1, 2, dsh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  let idx = colB.indexOf(did);
  if (~idx) {
    dsh.getRange(idx, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[fsh.getRange("E2").getValue(), fsh.getRange("A3").getValue()]]);//update
  } else {
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[fsh.getRange("E2").getValue(), fsh.getRange("A3").getValue()]]);//new data
  }
}
```

[Bitwise Not (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)